# Install PHP 8.2 on Oracle Linux Server 7

Tags: php, oraclelinux

Does anyone know how to install PHP 8.2 on this operating system, I have it virtualized, but the methods I usually follow to install it give me an old version, version 5
My teacher told me that there is a way to do it but the truth is I'm stuck and I don't know if PHP 8.2 is not compatible with OLS-7, help
Also for some reason the "def" command does not recognize it, as if it did not exist.

`sudo yum install -y oracle-php-release-el7`
`yum install -y php`
`yum update oracle-php-release-el7`
`yum update php`

Comment: If all else fails you can always [build from source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php)